# Finding all sql id, sql text, number of executions, execution time between two AWR snap ids in oracle

Tags: oracle, database-internals, awr

The AWR report provides the SQL information for top 10-20 SQL statements. Is it possible to get information on SQL statements that do not make it to the top list?  How do we find all sql id, sql text, number of executions, execution time between two AWR snap ids in oracle?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This will get those fields between 2 snap IDs, just replace the snap ID's in the where clause

```
select t.sql_id,
    t.sql_text,
    s.executions_total,
    s.elapsed_time_total
from DBA_HIST_SQLSTAT s, DBA_HIST_SQLTEXT t
where s.snap_id between 1000 and 2000;
```

Comment: You should at least apply some join between the tables

Comment: Oracle will just lazy equijoin the two tables, no reason to specify another type based on the question. If you had a reason to need to maintain the snippet with DBA's or developers who are more familiar with another type of db, then specifying inner join might be useful.

Comment: this is wrong, Oracle will do not equijoin. you have to join it by sql_id (and maybe dbid)

Answer (score 2):

You can select from the below views.

- Historical SQL statistics: [`DBA_HIST_SQLSTAT`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_3183.htm#REFRN23447)
- All SQL text: [`DBA_HIST_SQLTEXT`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_3184.htm#REFRN23448)
- Map snap_id to actual time: [`DBA_HIST_SNAPSHOT`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_3177.htm#REFRN23442)

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT T.SQL_ID,
         MIN (SN.BEGIN_INTERVAL_TIME)             BEGIN_INTERVAL_TIME,
         MAX (SN.END_INTERVAL_TIME)             END_INTERVAL_TIME,
         MAX (CAST (DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR (T.SQL_TEXT, 2000) AS NVARCHAR2 (2000)))             SQL_TEXT,
         SUM (S.EXECUTIONS_DELTA)                   EXECUTIONS,
         SUM (S.ELAPSED_TIME_DELTA)                 ELAPSED_TIME
    FROM DBA_HIST_SQLSTAT S, DBA_HIST_SQLTEXT T, DBA_HIST_SNAPSHOT SN
   WHERE     T.SQL_ID = S.SQL_ID
         AND S.SNAP_ID = SN.SNAP_ID
         AND SN.BEGIN_INTERVAL_TIME >= SYSDATE - 1
         AND SN.END_INTERVAL_TIME <= SYSDATE
GROUP BY T.SQL_ID
ORDER BY ELAPSED_TIME DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a join between `dba_hist_sqlstat` and `dba_hist_sqltext` or it will run forever:

```
select t.sql_id,
    t.sql_text,
    s.executions_total,
    s.elapsed_time_total
from DBA_HIST_SQLSTAT s, DBA_HIST_SQLTEXT t
where t.sql_id=s.sql_id and 
s.snap_id between 9349 and 9351
```

Also you need to make sure you have a license to the tuning pack, it's not free.